# C++ Sum of user inputted numbers less than 10

Tags: c++

I'm trying to complete a program that collects all user inputted numbers less than 10 and outputs the sum.

When I run it, the program adds the numbers that are < 10 to total, if a number is >= 10 we exit the loop and print the sum.

Here's what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {

int number, total;

cout << "Enter a number less than 10 to continue: " ;
cin >> number;

    while (number < 10){
       cout << "Enter a number less than 10 to continue: " ;
       cin >> number;
       total+=number;
    }

    if (number >= 10){
    cout << "The total amount is: " << total << endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Yep, on first look that seems ok, so what is your problem?

Comment: Sorry all, first time poster here.  Problem is when I compile it, if the user input is >= 10, it will be added into the total, and I only want the numbers that are less than 10.

Comment: swap `cout << "Enter a number less than 10 to continue: " ;` and `total+=number;` around in your while loop.

Comment: @NathanOliver Wow, swapping cout worked.  Cant believe it took me so long to figure out. Thank you!

Comment: `total` is not initialized before it's read in your code.

Comment: BTW, `total` is not initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your declared variables first.

```
int total = 0, number = 0;
```

The input in your loop is not checked before adding to the total. Take your input at the end of the loop body and then it will be checked on the next iteration.

```
while (number < 10){
   cout << "Enter a number less than 10 to continue: " ;
   //cin >> number;
   total+=number;
   cin >> number;
}
```